# Style a br like an hr

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an HTML block like this:

```
<div class="notice notice-info">
    <p class="status-explanations">
        <span class="header">Some title here</span><br>
        <span class="order-status status-on-hold">One status</span> some explanation text.<br>
        <span class="order-status status-processing">Another status</span> some other explanation.<br>
        <span class="order-status status-shipped">And another</span> and <span class="order-status status-awaiting-pickup">And one more</span> the explanation goes here<br>
        <span class="order-status status-completed">And yet another one</span> and its explanation.<br>
        <span class="order-status status-failed">This should be separated</span> with its explanation.<br>
        <span class="order-status status-cancelled">And finally this</span> the last one.
    </p>
</div>
```

The last two statuses need to be separated from the ones above them. So I changed `<br>` to `<hr>` but there must be some peculiarity with Wordpress and its content renderer, and so when `<hr>` gets rendered within the `<p>`, something strange happens, and a closing `</p>` appears just above `<hr>` and the rest two of the `<span>` statuses stay outside of the `<p>` (I noticed that because my CSS rules mention `<span>` statuses in reference to their parent `<p>`, so the ones outside of the `<p>` stay un-styled.

So my other idea is to add a class to the appropriate `<br>`, like `<br class="hr-style">` for that particular one that separates the two groups of statuses, and write an appropriate CSS rule to style the `<br>` like a horizontal line. But how do we add a horizontal line to a `<br>`? TIA

Comment: Can u share a graphical representation of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi https://i.ibb.co/BzFSg99/Screenshot-2022-06-11-175941.jpg